# How do I pass any array from ng-repeat to AngularJs attribute directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have a list of hierarchy of menu items where each item has a child list. For The menuItems property is from the controller scope(list of parents). I want to pass an array to be consumed by the directive on both levels of the following example.

Html Code

```
<div sortable="menuItems">
    <div ng-repeat="item in menuItems">
        ...
        <div sortable="item.Children">
            <div ng-repeat="child in menuItems.Children">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Directive code

```
app.directive('sortable', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $elem, attrs) {
         // I need access by the array in here.
        }
    };
});
```

I have set the sortable attribute to the value of the name of the list which obviously is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a scope watch (or collection watch), since the value of the attribute is the scope expression.

```
app.directive('sortable', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $elem, attrs) {
             $scope.$watchCollection(attrs.sortable, function (newCollection, oldCollection) {
                 // (do something with newCollection)
             });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: says attrs is not defined so I must be doing something wrong here

Comment: Is `attrs` the exact name of the 3rd parameter to the `link` function? Or are you calling it `$attrs` in the function params and then trying to refer to `attrs` in the function body?

Comment: attrs.sortable is a string, not a collection, so until I get the array I haven't solved my issue. I need the array from the directive attribute sortable="menuItems" somehow to be available in my link function.

Comment: @jwize Yes, that is exactly what you get inside the watch listener function - `newCollection` will be that array. By watching the `attrs.sortable` string, AngularJS will evaluate that expression and invoke the listener once initially and then afterwards for any changes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the isolate-scope for the directive was not set.

```
app.directive('sortable', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, $elem, attrs) {...},
        scope: { items: '=' }
    }

   <div id="sortable-basic" sortable items="menuItems">
```